# $\overline{X_n}$ and $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i-\overline{X_n}|$ independent if $X_i\sim N(0,1)$ independent

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, independence

From https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.j.k.kleijn/AsympStat-LecNotes2010.pdf

This question is about problem 2.10:
"Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent standard normal variables. Show that $\overline{X_n}$ and $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i-\overline{X_n}|$ are independent."

It seems like this is like proving that the sample mean and sample variance are independent. I also thought of the distribution of $X_i-\overline{X_n}$, but that has little sense since $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,\overline{X_n})\neq 0$. Hoping that this pdf is just $N(0,1)$, I would use the fact $\operatorname{Cov}(\overline{X_n},X_i-\overline{X_n})=0$. Then by some lemma it would follow that $\overline{X_n}$ is independent of $X_i-\overline{X_n}$. But then we have not even had the sum..

Thanks in advance for all what can be called help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two random variables are **jointly** normally distributed then they are independent if their covariance is zero. And they are *jointly* normally distributed if they are both linear combinations of *independent* normally distributed random variables. You've already seen that $\operatorname{cov}(\,\overline X_n, X_i - \overline X_n\,)=0.$ That gets you independence of $\overline X_n$ and the vector $(X_i-\overline X_n : i=1,\ldots,n).$ If $g$ is any (non-random) function of $n$ variables, then independence of $\overline X_n$ and $g(\,X_i-\overline X_n : i=1,\ldots,n\,)$ follows.

PS: It would seem that the needed lemma is as follows:

> Suppose $V_1,\ldots,V_k,W_1,\ldots,W_\ell$ are **jointly** normally distributed and the $k\times\ell$ matrix $\operatorname{cov}(V,W)$ is $0$, where $V$ is the $k\times1$ column whose entries are $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ and $W$ is the corresponding $\ell\times1$ column, then $V\mathbin{\bot\!\!\!\bot} W.$

Comment: "Jointly" is the same as "multivariate"? About the second phrase you wrote: what about $(X,X)$ if $X\sim N(0,1)$? I think this variable is not multivariate normal distributed.

Comment: Yes: "jointly normal" means having a multivariate normal distribution. That is stronger than each of the random variables separately being normally distributed. The pair $(X,X)$ does have a bivariate normal distribution if $X\sim N(0,1).$ One statement often used as the definition is that $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate normal distribution if for every pair of constant (i.e. non-random) coefficients $a,b,$ the random variable $aX+bY$ is normally distributed. $\qquad$

Comment: Oh ok, yes I agree $(\overline{X_n},X_i-\overline{X_n})$ does have a multivariate normal distribution. Now I am convinced that $\overline{X_n}$ is independent of $X_i-\overline{X_n}$. But it is not true in general that if $X_i-\overline{X_n}$ is independent of $\overline{X_n}$ then $\overline{X_n}$ is independent of the whole vector. If it is true in this case, then I agree with the following step you gave about $g$.

Comment: @RoccovanVreumingen : I think you're right about that last statement, but it's true in a multivariate normal setting.

Comment: Where did you find this lemma? And do you mean that $(V_1,...,V_k)$ and $(W_1,...,W_{\ell})$ are multivariate normally distributed, or $(V_1,...,V_k,W_1,...,W_{\ell})$?

Comment: You need to assume $(V_1,\ldots,V_k,W_1,\ldots,W_\ell)$ has a multivariate normal distribution. The lemma is found in standard accounts of that distribution.

Comment: @RoccovanVreumingen : Suppose $$ \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} \sim N\left( \begin{bmatrix} \mu_X \\ \mu_Y  \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_X & \Sigma_{XY} \\ \Sigma_{YX} & \Sigma_Y \end{bmatrix} \right) $$ where $\Sigma_X$ is a $k\times k$ nonnegative-definite matrix and $\Sigma_Y$ similarly $\ell\times\ell$, so $\Sigma_{XY}$ is $k\times\ell$ and $\Sigma_{YX}$ is its transpose. Then the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is $$ N(\mu_Y + \Sigma_{YX} \Sigma_X^{-1}(X-\mu_X),\ \Sigma_Y - \Sigma_{YX} \Sigma_X^{-1} \Sigma_{XY}). $$ Therefore$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$if $\Sigma_{XY} = 0,$ then the conditional distribution is $ N(\mu_U, \Sigma_Y). $ Thus in that case the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ does not depend on $X,$ and therefore $X,Y$ are independent. Quod erat demonstrandum. $\qquad$

Comment: Almost all is clear now but the conditional distribution. I have taken a look at "conditional" using control f. Only one time found in a chapter where I'm not already. But before we go on maybe it's good to say that in a similar exercise where they asked why $\overline{X_n}$ is independent of the vector $(X_i-\overline{X_n}:i)$, the teacher wrote in a guide that "independent" has to be replaced by "uncorrelated". I sent a mail why that is so and now I'm waiting for an answer. So would it be a good idea that the event "going on" and "answer to that email" are dependent?

Comment: First I thought that this correction in the guide could have been ignored, but now I'm hesitating because I'm asking very much in the comments.

Comment: Got it! The lemma you gave was an earlier question I asked and that already has an answer. So I believe the lemma is true and from that it's done.